# The control does not flow beyond 45th line

Tags: c, function

The question is as follows.

Q) Develop a function f1 to accept an integer argument, reverse the digits and return the reversed value. Also, develop another function f2 to accept two integer arguments x and n and to return the value of x raised to the power n. The return value of f2 should be passed on to f1 and the return value of f1 must be checked whether it is prime or not by another function f3. The result must be printed in the program.

The control does not flow beyond the 45th line in this code. I do not really know what it the issue here because when i run the code in code blocks, the output screen displays the output of f2 and then it remains idle. for example, if i give the input as 8 and 2, then the output returns a value of 81 and then it does not do anything beyond that.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int f1(int npow)
    {
        int ret=0;
        while (npow>0)
        {
            ret=(ret*10)+(npow%10);
        }
        return ret;
    }
    int f2(int x,int n)
    {
        int res;
        res=pow(x,n);
        return res;
    }
    int f3(int resrev)
    {
        int i,check;
        for (i=2;i<resrev;i++)
        {
            if (resrev%i==0)
            {
                check =1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                check=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        return check;
    }
    void main()
    {
        int resrev,x,n,npow,prime;
        printf("Enter two numbers x and n\n");
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&n);
        npow=f2(x,n);
        printf("x to the power n is %d\n",npow);
        resrev=f1(npow);
        printf("Reversed value of x to the power n is %d \n",resrev);
        prime=f3(resrev);
        if (prime==1)
            printf("It is not a prime number \n");
        else
            printf("It is a prime number\n");
    }
```

Comment: `npow` is not altered within a loop of `f1` and it is a infinite loop

Comment: This is a good opportunity to learn how to use your debugger to single step.  Then you'll be able to see more about what your code is doing instead of "it remains idle".

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in function `f1`. It is an infinite loop.

**Loop condition is *until npow>0* but you are not updating value of `npow` in the loop.**
Following is corrected code:

```
int f1(int npow)
{
    int ret=0;
    while (npow>0)
    {
        ret=(ret*10)+(npow%10);
        npow = npow/10;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop inside `f1` is infinite as condition to exit while loop is unaltered.

snippet has to be updated as follows,

```
int f1(int npow)
{
   int ret=0;
   while (npow>0)
   {
        ret=(ret*10)+(npow%10);
        npow /= 10; // divide to remove lsb digit
   }
   return ret;
}
```